# ¿Cómo trabajo modularmente una vista en el patron MVC con php?

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo estas carpetas **modelo, vista, controlador y libs**.

Dentro de modelo tengo por ejemplo una clase llamada **main.php** que tiene en el `__construct()` un "hola mundo"; por ejemplo, luego en **libs** tengo una clase `app` que en su `__construct()` solo tiene una forma de expulsar las url para recorrer el sitio, en controlador un archivo **mainControl.php** que solo comunica el modelo y la vista, y en vista pues un platilla, y por ultimo un archivo en la raíz llamado **index.php** que solo tiene instanciado la clase `app`.

La pregunta es, yo quiero trabajar mi vista modularmente, o sea, quiero reutilizar código de mi plantillas, por ejemplo la barra de navegación quiero ponerla en un archivo **navbar.php** que solo contenga la barra y llamarla cada vez que quiera un plantilla nueva en la vista esto como ejemplo, ¿esto se puede en este patrón, como lo trabajaría?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos lo que has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: bueno, tengo lo siguiente:
<html lang="es">
<? 
require_once"partes/head.php";

?>
<body>
<?
require_once "partes/navbar.php";
require_once"partes/contenedor.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
esto esta en mi carpeta vista, y la carperta partes es la que acabo de añadir pero no se si al hacelo rompo el patron MVC, no se si soy claro con la pregunta.
Yo quiero reutilizar la el codigo de la navbar y resto en otras vista para que no se vea tan gigante el codigo.

Comment: Agrega el código en la pregunta, haz click en el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/345474/edit) que está abajo de ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello te recomiendo que con `composer` hagas una autocarga de clases desde el **composer.json**. Poder lograrlo tus archivos y carpetas deben seguir el patrón `PSR-4`.

En el **composer.json** debes establecer todas las cargas de tus clases de esta manera:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
   }
}
```

Donde **Acme** es el nombre de tu **namespace** y **src/** la ruta en donde se encuentran tus clases.

Luego que finalices la configuración no olvides ejecutar `$ composer dump_autoload`

Para que tu **index** redireccione la URL a tus vistas necesitas un archivo **.htaccess** en la ruta donde se encuentra tu **index** y a su vez cargar el archivo **autoload** de `composer`.

Para ello necesitaras ademas un archivo para manjar tus rutas con una clase con un método parecido a este ejemplo:

```
class Route
{


    public static $validRoutes = array();

    public static function set($route, $function)
    {
        //$_GET['url'] = '';

        self::$validRoutes[] = $route;
        if(!empty($_GET['URL'])){

            if ($_GET['url'] == $route) {

                call_user_func($function);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Adicionalmente, necesitas un archivo para redirigir las vistas a tus archivos `php`, como por ejemplo:

```
abstract class Controller
{
    public static function viewFile($view)
    {
       require_once "../resources/views/$view.php";
    }

    public static function view($file, $values)
    {
        require_once "../resources/views/$file.php";
    }

}
```

Adicionalmente, necesitas los controladores, y los modelos para tus bases de datos. Tu pregunta es muy general y abarca muchísimo contenido, te aconsejo que primero la atomices un poco más y la dividas de una forma en la que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Si lo que estás intentando es construir tu propio framework esta bien, pero no trates de abarcar todo de una vez, ve desarrollando módulo por módulo. Ahora si lo que necesitas es una infraestructura para comenzar a trabajar mejor te recomiendo es irte por un Framework como `Symfony`, `Laravel` entre otros que trabajan con el paradigma `MVC` y aplican más capas, como por ejemplo una entre tantas la de `middleware`.

Para las vistas y las plantillas (momentaneamente) en el framework que estoy haciendo las estoy trabajando en una carpeta que nombré partials, ahí tengo guardado dos archivos uno que se llama header.php y otro con el nombre footer.php donde tengo almacenada la siguiente información:

header.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/honey.png" type="image/png">
        <title>Miel FW</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
```

footer.php:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y cuando necesito crear una vista con contenido completo lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<?php include ('./partials/header.php') ?>

<div class="content">
 <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
</div>


<?php include ('./partials/footer.php')?>
```

Si quieres hacerlo con motores de plantillas tendrías que incorporar uno como Twig o crear tu propio motor de plantillas.

Saludos.

Comment: Por qué el controlador debe ser una clase abstracta?

Comment: Además que el OP no está preguntando esto, sino que como reusar segmentos de códigos de sus vistas

Comment: bueno, sobre el composer esta bien, pero quería poder reutilizar fragmentos de códigos de mis vistas, no quiero que cada vez que me toque hacer un vista nueva volver hacer toda la estructura HTML desde cero sino importarla con require para no volver a escribir lo mismo.

Comment: Yo te plantearia que empezaras a usar una librería de plantillas como twig. De esta manera, aunque a tu controlador le indiques una plantilla, puedes utilizar toda la potencia de twig para hacer herencia, inclusión y demás de partes de plantilla (bloques)

Comment: Voy a modificar la pregunta para cambiar la respuesta, pero lo que te dice Jakala es una forma de resolver tu problema, trabajar con plantillas como Blade o Twig. En la respuesta te voy a explicar momentaneamente como lo resolví yo.

Comment: @BetaM Para que esa clase no pueda ser instanciada, sino heredada o extendida.